# Plotting MOS resistances in transmission gates in spice

Tags: circuit-design, cmos, spice, vlsi, transmission-gate

I am trying to plot the resistance of MOS transistors in transmission gates, as a function of output voltage in ltSpice, as shown in this figure from Jan.M.Rabey:
[image]

I have a circuit with same specifications and plotted DC sweep at input voltage V6. I have this graph:

[image: Blue one is resistance plot, red is output voltage and green is drain current]

Basically the output voltage follows input very closely so potential difference for NMOS is nearly zero for most of the time and I am unable to comprehend the resistance curve. Can anyone please explain this ambiguity .

Thanks

Comment: When using the `nmos4` and `pmos4` symbols you need to connect the body terminals, in this case to VSS and VDD respectively.  These terminals are floating in your schematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Can anyone please explain this ambiguity*

- You have no load on the transmission gate output
- Therefore no DC current passes through it
- Therefore there is no volt drop caused by the resistance of the transmission gate
- Therefore output voltage and input voltage in a DC plot will be almost identical (if not truly identical)

Is this enough to see where your mistake is?

Comment: Yes, I think I should have gone for transient response, as I have captive load, so it will take some time to charge while the current will flow through it, giving us time varying resistance. Right ?

Comment: You have a capacitive load and, in DC analysis, the capacitors will be presumed to have fully charged to their operating point and, as a result of this, the DC analysis will ignore their presence.

Comment: Can you tell me how to get the graphical relation that I want ?

Comment: DC analysis is fine but, without a current passing through the transmission gate, you won't get a volt drop across the transmission gate. Other than that, I can't tell you how to get the graphical relation that you want if I don't know what you want. I only see DC analysis in your question.

Comment: I want to see the variation of MOS resistances with output voltage in spice. But I am unable to get the resistance values due to zero DC current. I am trying to do transient analysis now

Comment: Remember what I said here `You have no load on the transmission gate output` $$$$ Remember what I said here `Therefore no DC current passes through it`$$$$ Do those two things not mean anything to you?

Comment: Transient analysis without a load resistor will be no different to DC analysis without a load resistor. Use a load resistor **OR** short the output to 0 volts and use a current source (not a voltage source) in DC analysis.

Comment: He also needs to connect the body terminals for the 4-terminal MOSFETs to VDD and VSS.  They are floating in his schematic.