# Transmission gate conducting in OFF state

Tags: analog, cmos, virtuoso

Here is a part of my circuit that I am trying to simulate in cadence virtuoso. It has two transmission gates, the one in path of charging the capacitor is on and other one is OFF. Supply voltage is kept at 1V and MOS dimensions are L=45nm , W=300nm for first stage and W=120nm for second stage. Here is the schemtic for the same.

[image]

[image]

I observe that the voltage at floating net at output of OFF transmission gate is around 0.8V. How does this happen if this gate is OFF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I observe that the voltage at floating net at output of OFF
> transmission gate is around 0.8V. How does this happen if this gate is
> OFF*

It happens because MOSFETs have leakage current (i.e. it's not a truly floating net) and your measurement device is virtual tool with infinite input impedance. Of course this will happen! I'd be surprised if it didn't.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Can you please elaborate on how this happens, or share some good reading material on this

Comment: MOSFETs **never** have zero conduction; it's a fact of life. So, if you replaced the MOSFETs with 10 Mohm resistors to "emulate" and "open-circuit" MOSFET you'd still get a voltage produced. I can't recommend good reading because it's been decades since I read any basic stuff on MOSFETs and I wouldn't know what constitutes good beginner reading if I saw it. Anyway, I've given you the electrical idea with 10 Mohm resistors representing an open-circuit MOSFET @Sparsh

Comment: I also suggest that this is very much related to your earlier question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/599186/plotting-mos-resistances-in-transmission-gates-in-spice and I answered that one along the same lines.

Comment: Got your point, but in this case, leakage current is high enough to increase voltage of other end to 0.8V when VDD=1V. Is'nt it too much ?

Comment: Well, maybe your virtual measurement instrument is designed to mimic a 10 Mohm input real instrument. Maybe there is another leakage current through the bulk diodes in the MOSFETs @Sparsh - try loading the output with 1 Mohm. You know; have a little mess around with things.

Comment: @Sparsh are we finished with this Q and  session now?

Comment: yes, thanks for your support

Comment: @Sparsh are you aware of the procedure for closing down the session: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour